# how to embed texts from database to an image and generate a jpg file

Tags: string, image, embed

I've an image. I want to retrieve datas from the database and embed the datas in specific locations in the image and then generate a final version of the image including the datas from the database and allow users to save it as a jpg file.
Can anyone help me achieve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) is the old gorilla in the room; I've used the command-line tools to resize a few thousand images before (which was great) but I hear its API is cumbersome.

[gd](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page) is newer, but I've heard good things about it. Never tried it.

If you include your programming languages of choice, that might influence other people's suggestions.

Comment: Im using PHP.
Thanks for your help.